# why isn't rpm release tag redundant?

Tags: rpm

From rpm `.spec` file documentation, the `version` tag is intended to correspond to the version of the software being packaged.  But the `release` tag is intended to increment with a new build of the `.rpm`.

What is the point of the `release` tag then??

If the software has not changed in the meantime and the version is the same, then by definition the software is and behaves the same, and the `.rpm` file will be exactly as before, so the release should be the same.  Suppose the original `.rpm` file is lost so I need to recreate it, and there are no changes, then, of course the recreated file should be exactly like before - that is what one wants in case of no changes to the software.

I don't get the need for the `release` tag, please explain this to me.

Added: the docs at `http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-tags.html` say

(...)If it is necessary to repackage that software at the same version, the release should be incremented.(...)

Maybe that is not what they mean?  Maybe what is really intended here is, "repackage the software at the same version, but there may be minor changes which do not deserve to be a new version, so we just increment the release instead".  Is that what is really meant here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of factors that go into a binary RPM file, beyond just an upstream version of the source code. Compiler/configure options, default config files, init scripts, pre/post install actions, and the set of files packaged. Any one of these might need to be changed after the initial build. For example, for Heartbleed, one might want to rebuild OpenSSL with the heartbeat feature turned off. In this case, the upstream version hasn't changed and there needs to be some way to distinguish the two builds. The `release` tag enables this.

Comment: In the case you are describing, these are changes to the software. The build process is part of the software product. If you change the build process, that is a new version of the software.  Same question again, if nothing changes (including the build), why is `release` needed?

Comment: No, they are not changes to the software and they do not change the upstream version number. OpenSSL 1.0.1f compiled with or without the `-DOPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS` configure option is still the **same** upstream OpenSSL 1.0.1f. The `release` tag allows tracking the choices made by the packager for different builds of the exact same version of the source.

Comment: OK I think we disagree on what constitutes a software product and version. To me, what you are describing, is a different software product, or version, or both. But let's agree to disagree, that was not my question. What I get from you, is one case where you argue a different release is needed: a change in the build process on a build command line, and no other changes.  Are there other cases for the need for a new release?

Comment: Yes, several others mentioned in the answer: a packager-supplied init script could have a bug in it, a packager-supplied configuration file could have an error in it, or the packager might initially package the wrong set of files (either by including something unnecessary or omitting something necessary). In all of these cases, the upstream version of the source (and even the content of the compiled files) is unchanged, so the release tag gets incremented to indicate the difference.